# Zabbix psql active monitoring is not supported

Tags: zabbix

I have Zabbix agent in active mode and psql monitoring is not working.It is not supported, I don't know what it means...

Zabbix server message:

[image]

Agent log file:

```
 36170:20170103:023837.264 Starting Zabbix Agent [xxxxx]. Zabbix 2.2.7 (revision 50148).
 36170:20170103:023837.264 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
 36170:20170103:023837.270 Starting agent module libzbxpgsql 1.0.0
 36170:20170103:023837.271 loaded modules: libzbxpgsql.so
 36171:20170103:023837.271 agent #0 started [collector]
 36172:20170103:023837.272 agent #1 started [listener #1]
 36173:20170103:023837.272 agent #2 started [listener #2]
 36174:20170103:023837.273 agent #3 started [listener #3]
 36175:20170103:023837.273 agent #4 started [active checks #1]

 36175:20170103:024841.219 active check "psql.active_connections[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.219 active check "psql.buffers_alloc[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.219 active check "psql.buffers_backend[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.219 active check "psql.buffers_backend_fsync[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.219 active check "psql.buffers_checkpoint[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.buffers_clean[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.checkpoints_req[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.checkpoints_timed[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.tx_commited[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.server_connections[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.idle_connections[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.idle_tx_connections[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.220 active check "psql.locks_waiting[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.server_maxcon[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.maxwritten_clean[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.running[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.tx_rolledback[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.slow_dml_queries[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw,10]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.slow_queries[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw,10]" is not supported
 36175:20170103:024841.221 active check "psql.slow_select_queries[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw,10]" is not supported
```

config file:

```
    # This is a config file for the Zabbix agent daemon (Unix)
# To get more information about Zabbix, visit http://www.zabbix.com

############ GENERAL PARAMETERS #################

### Option: PidFile
#   Name of PID file.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid

PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid

### Option: LogFile
#   Name of log file.
#   If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=

LogFile=/var/log/zabbix-agent/zabbix_agentd.log

### Option: LogFileSize
#   Maximum size of log file in MB.
#   0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1

LogFileSize=0

### Option: DebugLevel
#   Specifies debug level
#   0 - no debug
#   1 - critical information
#   2 - error information
#   3 - warnings
#   4 - for debugging (produces lots of information)
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-4
# Default:
# DebugLevel=3

### Option: SourceIP
#   Source IP address for outgoing connections.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# SourceIP=

### Option: EnableRemoteCommands
#   Whether remote commands from Zabbix server are allowed.
#   0 - not allowed
#   1 - allowed
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# EnableRemoteCommands=0

### Option: LogRemoteCommands
#   Enable logging of executed shell commands as warnings.
#   0 - disabled
#   1 - enabled
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogRemoteCommands=0

##### Passive checks related

### Option: Server
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses (or hostnames) of Zabbix servers.
#   Incoming connections will be accepted only from the hosts listed here.
#   If IPv6 support is enabled then '127.0.0.1', '::127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1' are treated equally.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Server=

Server=127.0.0.1,88.198.52.25

### Option: ListenPort
#   Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
# ListenPort=10050

### Option: ListenIP
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
#   First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ListenIP=0.0.0.0

### Option: StartAgents
#   Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
#   If set to 0, disables passive checks and the agent will not listen on any TCP port.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-100
# Default:
# StartAgents=3

##### Active checks related

### Option: ServerActive
#   List of comma delimited IP:port (or hostname:port) pairs of Zabbix servers for active checks.
#   If port is not specified, default port is used.
#   IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
#   If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
#   If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
#   Example: ServerActive=127.0.0.1:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ServerActive=

ServerActive=88.198.52.25

### Option: Hostname
#   Unique, case sensitive hostname.
#   Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
#   Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Hostname=

Hostname=system.wroc.wiw.gov.pl

### Option: HostnameItem
#   Item used for generating Hostname if it is undefined. Ignored if Hostname is defined.
#   Does not support UserParameters or aliases.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# HostnameItem=system.hostname

### Option: HostMetadata
#   Optional parameter that defines host metadata.
#   Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
#   An agent will issue an error and not start if the value is over limit of 255 characters.
#   If not defined, value will be acquired from HostMetadataItem.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-255 characters
# Default:
# HostMetadata=

### Option: HostMetadataItem
#   Optional parameter that defines an item used for getting host metadata.
#   Host metadata is used at host auto-registration process.
#   During an auto-registration request an agent will log a warning message if
#   the value returned by specified item is over limit of 255 characters.
#   This option is only used when HostMetadata is not defined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# HostMetadataItem=

### Option: RefreshActiveChecks
#   How often list of active checks is refreshed, in seconds.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 60-3600
# Default:
# RefreshActiveChecks=120

### Option: BufferSend
#   Do not keep data longer than N seconds in buffer.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-3600
# Default:
# BufferSend=5

### Option: BufferSize
#   Maximum number of values in a memory buffer. The agent will send
#   all collected data to Zabbix Server or Proxy if the buffer is full.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 2-65535
# Default:
# BufferSize=100

### Option: MaxLinesPerSecond
#   Maximum number of new lines the agent will send per second to Zabbix Server
#   or Proxy processing 'log' and 'logrt' active checks.
#   The provided value will be overridden by the parameter 'maxlines',
#   provided in 'log' or 'logrt' item keys.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-1000
# Default:
# MaxLinesPerSecond=100

############ ADVANCED PARAMETERS #################

### Option: Alias
#   Sets an alias for an item key. It can be used to substitute long and complex item key with a smaller and simpler one.
#   Multiple Alias parameters may be present. Multiple parameters with the same Alias key are not allowed.
#   Different Alias keys may reference the same item key.
#   For example, to retrieve the ID of user 'zabbix':
#   Alias=zabbix.userid:vfs.file.regexp[/etc/passwd,^zabbix:.:([0-9]+),,,,\1]
#   Now shorthand key zabbix.userid may be used to retrieve data.
#   Aliases can be used in HostMetadataItem but not in HostnameItem parameters.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range:
# Default:

### Option: Timeout
#   Spend no more than Timeout seconds on processing
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-30
# Default:
# Timeout=3

### Option: AllowRoot
#   Allow the agent to run as 'root'. If disabled and the agent is started by 'root', the agent
#   will try to switch to user 'zabbix' instead. Has no effect if started under a regular user.
#   0 - do not allow
#   1 - allow
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# AllowRoot=0

### Option: Include
#   You may include individual files or all files in a directory in the configuration file.
#   Installing Zabbix will create include directory in /etc/zabbix, unless modified during the compile time.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Include=

# Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.userparams.conf
# Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/

####### USER-DEFINED MONITORED PARAMETERS #######

### Option: UnsafeUserParameters
#   Allow all characters to be passed in arguments to user-defined parameters.
#   0 - do not allow
#   1 - allow
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1
# Default:
# UnsafeUserParameters=0

### Option: UserParameter
#   User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
#   Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
#   See 'zabbix_agentd' directory for examples.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# UserParameter=

####### LOADABLE MODULES #######

### Option: LoadModulePath
#   Full path to location of agent modules.
#   Default depends on compilation options.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LoadModulePath=${libdir}/modules

### Option: LoadModule
#   Module to load at agent startup. Modules are used to extend functionality of the agent.
#   Format: LoadModule=<module.so>
#   The modules must be located in directory specified by LoadModulePath.
#   It is allowed to include multiple LoadModule parameters.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
LoadModule=libzbxpgsql.so
```

verbose log:

```
129967: 45220:20170103:125411.785 active check "psql.checkpoints_req[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]" is not supported
129968: 45220:20170103:125411.785 for key [psql.checkpoints_timed[127.0.0.1,5432,postgres,raban_wiw]] received value [ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED]
129969: 45220:20170103:125411.785 In process_value() key:'system.wroc.wiw.gov.pl:psql.checkpoints_timed[{$PGHOST},{$PGPORT},{$PGROLE},{$PGDATABASE}]' value:'ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your agent is not configured to have any of the `psql.*` userparameters that are needed for those item keys to work, unless you have them in some included file.

You should get the userparameter configuration from the same place you obtained this template. It looks like you have unlinked the template from the host in question, though - that is probably not a good idea, better keep the template linked.

And consider reading about [Zabbix userparameters](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/userparameters) in the official manual, it should make it more clear how this is supposed to work.

It has been suggested that the [libzbxpgsql](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/libzbxpgsql) [loadable module](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/loadablemodules) is supposed to provide these item keys. If so, setting the agent [DebugLevel](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd) parameter to 4 and checking for more useful error messages might help, but that is probably what you already have provided as "verbose log". If so, doublecheck that the Zabbix user (or whichever your agent runs as) can connect to PostgreSQL on 127.0.0.1:5432 with the "postgres" role.

Note that the [template](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/libzbxpgsql/blob/master/template_postgresql_server.xml), supposed to be used with that loadable module, has completely different item keys - yours start with `psql.`, while the template ones start with `pg.`. The easiest might be dropping all your previous configuration and reinstalling the latest version of the odule and template.

Comment: "loaded modules: libzbxpgsql.so" => module cavaliercoder/libzbxpgsql is used.

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase agent loglevel and then recheck agent logs. Probably PSQL permission problem. Also I recommend to upgrade your agent. Then you may see error message in Zabbix UI instead of `ZBX_UNSUPPORTED`.